# Write data from MySQL to remote server

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

I have a MySQL database on one server. When users create a post, their post gets saved into the database. The server that the users are using is a slow server and I'd like to transfer the data to a remove server I have built. It can be a live connection where whenever a user posts a post, that remote server receives the details regarding that post. The remote server will process it and basically ping an API.

I'd like to understand what is the best way to build an architecture like this. Currently, there's around 2,000 posts a day, so not really big data. I was thinking of using Kafka where the remote server could read from the Kafka pipeline on the user server as the messages came through. Is this solution a good solution or are there better solutions to explore?

Comment: Do you already have a Kafka cluster? If not, why cannot you use a remote replica?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't have a Kafka cluster, I was thinking of setting a standalone kafka server and sending the messages use a MySQL to Kafka connector like Debezium. If I use a remote replica of the database, how would I send any new updates to that database?

Comment: A replica is not the same as an offline copy. You can keep them in sync as well, via similar mechanisms that Debezium would require https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Would replication be similar to a master slave architecture?

Comment: Not exactly since that would require two way replication